# using preg_replace to keep a part of a string with php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following string.

```
http://www.sample.com/profile/272353.html
```

I will like to use preg_replace to keep this part of the string.

```
profile/272353.html
```

The first part of the string changes so I just want to make sure to leave that part of the strng.

I am new to patterns and I still don't get it so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where does `preg_replace()` fit in to all this? There are a ton of ways to do this..

Comment: As @DavidHarris says below, use `parse_url`.  Regular expressions are not a magic wand that you should wave at every programming problem that happens to relate to strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use parse_url(...)

```
php > var_dump(parse_url('http://www.sample.com/profile/272353.html'));
array(3) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["host"]=>
  string(14) "www.sample.com"
  ["path"]=>
  string(22) "/profile/272353.html"
}
php >
```

Comment: Well like I said I am new so I am trying to approach this in whatever way its easier. Thank you for the function to break down the url but what if is not a well formatted URL or just part of that URL, I actually try that first and well the string that I am getting sometimes is not a url. The only reason why I was thinking of using preg_replace its because I have a function that I use to just keep numbers from a string by using the preg_replace function. I don't know if I am doing it correctly but it works. But any ideas on how to accomplish will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to answer the question as asked...

```
$modified = preg_replace("/.*([^\/]+\/[^\/]+$)/", $1, $string);
```